# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'

Tags: android, gradle, realm

I am getting below error when adding realm latest version in my app:

Gradle Console Error(using StackTrace):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

**Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug.
\> utf-8-**

\* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)



**Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: utf-8-**
    at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer$_sendAnalytics_closure12$_closure20.doCall(RealmTransformer.groovy:166)
    at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer$_sendAnalytics_closure12.doCall(RealmTransformer.groovy:160)
    at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer.sendAnalytics(RealmTransformer.groovy:159)
    at io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer.transform(RealmTransformer.groovy:149)
    at com.android.build.api.transform.Transform.transform(Transform.java:290)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.246 secs
```

**Below is are my gradle configurations:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Anyone did face this problem? can you help me out or find out what would be issue in my case?

Comment: It appears to me that you can try to explicitly disable the transformer analytics using an [environment parameter called REALM_DISABLE_ANALYTICS](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm-transformer/src/main/groovy/io/realm/transformer/RealmTransformer.groovy#L181) if its value is `true`.

Comment: `REALM_DISABLE_ANALYTICS` checking is after this exception, so it won't fix the problem :( What is the encoding of your `build.gradle` file? Can you share the `build.gradle` file somewhere? You can send it to help@realm.io if you want to share it privately.

Comment: I am getting this error in every project with realm used. even downloaded realm official examples.

Comment: What character encoding do you use? And what are the locale settings of your operating system?

Comment: I have updated my question with OS locale details. please check.

Comment: Can you try to change your locale from `en_IN` to `en_IN.UTF8`?

Comment: still not solved I changed to `en_IN.UTF8` everywhere in `locale`.

Comment: Do you also see error messages when running `apt` on a command-line? These errors are  common if the specific locale isn't generated. See for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/463209/how-to-fix-locale-error.